# Unterschied zwischen “Laden”, “Geschäft” und “Ladengeschäft”

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Was sind die semantischen Unterschiede zwischen diesen drei Substantiven?

Abgesehen von den weiteren Bedeutungen des Wortes “Geschäft” (*Geschäfte machen* u.Ä.), was sind die Bedeutungsnuancen zwischen **Laden, Geschäft** und **Ladengeschäft**?

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, was für Nuancen du meinst. Jeder der drei Begriffe hat eine/mehrere Bedeutungen (siehe Duden) und manchmal trifft auf eine Sache einfach mehr als einer der Begriffe zu.

Comment: Dann ist da noch der Geschäftsladen. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich erweitere die Fragestellung um ein paar verwandte Begriffe.

Ein *Ladengeschäft* oder *Ladenlokal* ist ein Gebäudeteil, in
dem ein Geschäft eingerichtet ist oder eingerichtet werden kann.
Man mietet ein *Ladengeschäft*, um darin einen Blumenladen
oder ein Uhrengeschäft zu betreiben;
die Begriffe bezeichnen also primär die Räume, nicht das
Unternehmen selbst.

Im Gegensatz dazu benutzt man die Begriffe *Laden*, *Geschäft*,
und (in Zusammensetzungen) *-Handlung* sowohl für ein Handelsunternehmen
als auch für dessen Räumlichkeiten.
Die drei Begriffe sind also grundsätzlich synonym,
unterscheiden sich aber leicht im Gebrauch:

Der Begriff *Laden* hat gewisse Konnotationen, die
*Geschäft* und *-Handlung* fehlen.
Man assoziiert mit *Laden* traditionell ein eher kleines Geschäft,
das nicht Teil eines großen Konzerns ist
(*Tante-Emma-Laden*),
nicht sehr hochpreisige Waren
(*Blumenladen*, aber nicht *Uhrenladen*),
und seit den Siebzigerjahren
häufig ein alternatives
Image (*Hofladen*, *Dritte-Welt-Laden*, *Bioladen*).
*Laden* ist auch der einzige der drei Begriffe, der despektierlich
gebraucht werden kann
(*"Saftladen!"*, *"Was ist denn das hier für ein Laden!"*)

Die Unterscheidung zwischen *Geschäft* und *-Handlung* ist
demgegenüber schwieriger.
*Handlung* wird nur in Zusammensetzungen gebraucht,
üblicherweise in Kombination mit der verkauften Ware
(*Buchhandlung*, *Eisenwarenhandlung*)
und fast nie in Kombination mit der Bezeichung des
Verkäufers (*Juwelierhandlung* ist extrem unüblich).
Für das *Geschäft* gibt es dagegen keine solchen Einschränkungen.
Häufig gibt es je nach Handelsware eine klare Präferenz
für einen der Begriffe

- *Blumenladen* > *Blumengeschäft* > *Blumenhandlung*,
- *Lebensmittelgeschäft* > *Lebensmittelladen* > *Lebensmittelhandlung*,
- *Eisenwarenhandlung* > *Eisenwarengeschäft* > *Eisenwarenladen*,
- *Buchhandlung* > *Buchladen* > *Buchgeschäft*,

aber warum im Einzelfall der eine gegenüber dem anderen
bevorzugt wird, ist wohl oft nur durch die Tradition zu erklären.

Comment: Welche Bezeichnung bevorzugt wird, ist vermutlich auch regional unterschiedlich. Ich stamme aus Berlin und würde sowohl "Lebensmittelladen" als auch "Eisenwarenladen" als bevorzugte Version verwenden. Bei "Buchhandlung" und "Buchladen" bin ich unsicher. Tendenziell würde ich "Buchhandlung" eher bei einem grüßeren Laden verwenden und "Buchladen" eher bei einem kleineren Laden.

Answer (score 2):

Das *Geschäft* ist ein Überbegriff für Firmen aller Art, d. h. auch ich gehe morgens ins *Geschäft* arbeiten, aber nicht in einen Laden.
Unter einem *Laden* versteht man im direkten Sinne ein Einzelhandelsgeschäft, d. h. ein Geschäft mit einer Verkaufsfläche.
Man kann ihn aber auch auf größere Geschäfte anwenden, die nicht mal zum Einzelhandel gehören; dann aber indirekt und pejorativ, etwa *in was für einem Laden arbeitest **Du** denn? oder *X ist einfach ein Saftladen*.

Ein Ladengeschäft ist dann die Präzisierung eines Geschäfts - eben ein Geschäft mit einem Laden.

Comment: Und bevor einer morgens *ins Geschäft* geht (was ich übrigens für mundartig halte), macht er seinen *Laden* auf und *verrichtet sein Geschäft*.

Comment: Wieso geht man nicht in einen Laden arbeiten? Kann ich nicht nachvollziehen.