# Which word is preferred for "bookstore"?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice

I just noticed that there are two words which mean bookstore: der Buchladen and die Buchhandlung. Which of these two words is preferable? I'm using this in the context of "Ich gehe in die Buchhandlung (den Buchladen)."

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28636/unterschied-zwischen-laden-geschäft-und-ladengeschäft

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In cases like yours, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Buchhandlung%2C%20B%C3%BCcherladen%2C%20Buchladen%2C%20Buchgesch%C3%A4ft&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBuchhandlung%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CB%C3%BCcherladen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBuchladen%3B%2Cc0) gives you a good start.

You can clearly see that **Buchhandlung** is by far the most frequently used variety to describe stores selling books.

While in a more colloquial context a "Buch-" or "Bücherladen" will be both used and understood, "Buchhandlung" is correct in every register.

Answer (score 6):

*Buchladen* is the word that I would use in most cases, while *Buchhandlung* sounds more technical to me. Some of the other answers here let me suspect that there are regional differences, I am from Berlin.

As an example, I have found a list of [zehn tolle Buchläden in Berlin](https://www.qiez.de/berlin/shopping-mode/buecher-und-presse/zehn-tolle-buchlaeden-empfehlenswerte-buchhandlungen-in-berlin/170679941). There you see both words being used and also book stores having *Buchhandlung* or *Buchladen* in their name.

Looking at some other examples, it seems that *Buchladen* evokes the image of a smaller store.

Addendum: [Buchladen in München](https://www.haidhauserbuchladen.de), [Buchläden in Wien](http://www.diestadtspionin.at/reportagen/buchlaeden.php).

Answer (score 4):

Depends also on the type of bookstore. In every university town one can find a Universitätsbuchhandlung. Universitätsbuchladen would just sound terribly wrong. On the other hand, you can find here or there a feministic Frauenbuchladen. Frauenbuchhandlung would at least be uncommon.

Comment: Würde es falsch oder nur ungewöhnlich klingen? Kann man das am Klang unterscheiden?

Comment: Nicht am klang, aber es gibt doch eine gewisse Gewöhnung an Sprachrichtigkeit, oder?

Comment: Universitätsbuchladen klingt für mich ungewohnt, aber nicht falsch. Nach welcher Regel sollte es falsch sein? Frauenbuchhandlg. vs. -laden: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Frauenbuchladen%2CFrauenbuchhandlung&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFrauenbuchladen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CFrauenbuchhandlung%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Regel gibt es da keine. Aber richtig und falsch ergeben sich in der Sprache nun mal aus Konventionen, und die basieren letztendlich auf der Gewohnheit der Mehrheit.

Comment: Nein. Die Gewohnheit der Mehrheit ist die Konvention, daraus ergibt sich kein richtig und falsch. Die dt. Sprache erlaubt dem Sprecher/Schreiber spontane Wortbildungen; die sind dann ungewöhnlich aber nicht falsch.

Comment: Ja, schon. Worauf willst du hinaus?

Comment: Ob es falsch klingt. "Universitätsbuchladen would just sound terribly wrong."

Comment: Ja, entsprechend meiner Gewöhung an die deutsche Sprache KLINGT es falsch. Dass es im Sinne einer Regel falsch IST, habe ich nie zum Ausdruck gebracht.

Comment: Verstehe ich nicht. Wenn man weiß, dass das Gefühl, welches sich meldet, nur "ungewohnt" signalisiert, nicht "falsch", dass also "falsch" oft die falsche, überzogene Interpretation des Gefühls ist, wieso sagt man weiter "falsch" und nicht "ungewohnt"? Weil man die Ignoranz promoten will?

Comment: Wenn dir der Unterschied zwischen "es klingt falsch" und "es ist falsch" nicht klar ist, kann ich leider nicht helfen.

Answer (score 2):

Buchhandung is definitive preferable. Buchladen is nowhere near as idiomatic.

*Laden* is a colloquial term and you can make up all kind of *-läden*. People even call the place you can get doner kebab *Dönerladen*. Laden can also carry negative connotations: A *Saftladen*, for instance, is not a place where you can buy juice, but used to refer to any institution that provides bad service or bad products or is otherwise just not recommendable.

Comment: I can't think of even one case where I might have heard "Buchgeschäft". My first thought on hearing "Buchgeschäft" would be akin to "book business" - not the store, but the line of work.

Comment: As a native speaker of German, I would only use Buchhandlung.

Comment: @stephie Ja, ihr habt wohl recht. „Buchgeschäft“ ist standardsprachlich wirklich komisch. Ich habe mich hier von einem Regionalismus wohl etwas verleiten lassen.

Answer (score 0):

Buchladen? A Laden for books? No, no! Laden sounds like wild consumerism, but books that's the true, the beautiful and the good.

A Handlung on the other hand clearly feels like competence and seriousness. A book that is something of importance by itself, something that most be respected and honoured unlike eggs and cloths and therefore needs a proper Handlung instead of a Laden! It's a Kulturgut.

I clearly exaggerate here, but I belive that this idea somehow unspoken is in the mind of the average german or at least many germans. You can use Buchladen or idmean's Buchgeschäft e.g. in novels if you don't want to use Buchhandlung over and over again but in everyday German Buchhandlung is the common used word.

Comment: Handlung on its own means "action". How does "book action" make sense as a compound word? Or am I wrong to treat this word as a compound noun?

Comment: @ktm5124 It's indeed a compund word. It's just that Handlung as noun can mean store http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Handlung#Bedeutung3

Comment: Ich verstehe. Danke!

Comment: Ich widerspreche Ihrer Begründung, weil sie sich nicht verallgemeinern lässt. Ihrer Argumentation zufolge hörte sich ein _Kaufmannsladen_ nach wildem Konsum an, wohingegen _Kaufmannshandlung_ Kompetenz und Seriosität austrahlte und viele Durchschnittsdeutsche deshalb letzteres bevorzugen würden. Im zweiten Absatz schätzen Sie Eier und Kleidung herab, vermutlich, weil man sie eher im Laden kaufe?
 Getränke würde ich auf derselben Wertschätzungsstufe einordnen. Doch wie begründen sie dann, dass man eher _Getränkehandel_ statt _Getränkeladen_ sagt?

Comment: This is [clearly wrong](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinderladen).

Comment: I disagree. Like so often, I believe usage varies regionally. For example, to my Frankfurtian ears "Buchhandlung" sounds too formal, something you'd write to be "correct", but are unlikely to use in everyday speech to avoid sounding stiff or even lofty.